# Problem with Warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Tags: php, arrays, php-curl

My code to requets API has some error, I searched already but still dont know how to fix the problem with my current code. My code is being running at https://sa789.online/aaatest.php

```
    function Signature_Genarate($Params,$privateKey = false)
    {
        if(!empty($Params['signature']))
        {
            unset($Params['signature']);
        }
        ksort($Params);

        if(isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] ==1)
            echo implode("", $Params) . $privateKey;

        $Params['signature'] = sha1(implode("", $Params) . $privateKey);
        return $Params;
    }
    
    function Signature_Verify($Params , $privateKey = false)
    {
        if(!is_array($Params) || !$privateKey)
        {
            return false;   
        }
        
        $CSignature = '';
        if(!empty($Params['signature']))
        {
            $CSignature = $Params['signature'];
            unset($Params['signature']);
        }
        
        ksort($Params);
        $Signature = sha1(implode("", $Params) . $privateKey);
        return ($Signature === $CSignature) ? true : false;
    }
    
    $key = '9afdsfas1971adsfafewrfewqed7e360b6fads3b';
    $url = 'http://ag-webgame-staging.winroad168.com/api/wsv1_0/user_register';
    $params = [];
    $params['agid']          = 'EA003'; 
    $params['username']      = 'abc123456'; // min 6 max 20
    $params['password']      = '1q2w3e'; // min 6
    $params['lang']          = 'chs';
    $signature               = Signature_Genarate($params,$key);
    $params['lang']          = $signature;
    
    $paramsUrl = '';
    if ($params)
        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
            $paramsUrl .= (!empty($paramsUrl) ? "&" : "") . rawurlencode($key) . "=" . rawurlencode($value);

    $url = $url . '?' . $paramsUrl;
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($body,TRUE);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
```

And I got this

```
Warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/kwplyhje/public_html/aaatest.php on line 50
```

I am new and learning code so please help me the guide about fixing my code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `Signature_Genarate()` is an array, which you pass to `rawurlencode()`. `rawurlencode()` only accepts a string.

Try this instead:

```
    function Signature_Genarate($Params,$privateKey = false)
    {
        if(!empty($Params['signature']))
        {
            unset($Params['signature']);
        }
        ksort($Params);

        if(isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] ==1)
            echo implode("", $Params) . $privateKey;

        $Params['signature'] = sha1(implode("", $Params) . $privateKey);
        return $Params['signature']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `http_build_query()` function which accepts an array and generates an URL-encoded string for you

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);
echo http_build_query($data);
// will output foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

See the documentation here :: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Thank you for helping. And GlennM, you missed symboy ";" in the end of return $Params['signature']